# How to upload image in angularjs2 rc.3

Tags: angular, typescript

```
I have been trying to search for image upload in angularjs2 but i didnt find any that works.Can someone please suggest me help.
```

I have been trying to search for image upload in angularjs2 but i didnt find any that works.Can someone please suggest me help.

Comment: PrimeNG has a fileupload component you may try. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FileUploader} from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';

@Component({
  selector: 'simple-demo',
  template: <div>your template </div>,
})
export class SimpleDemoComponent {
  public uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: URL});
  public hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
  public hasAnotherDropZoneOver:boolean = false;

  public fileOverBase(e:any):void {
    this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
  }

  public fileOverAnother(e:any):void {
    this.hasAnotherDropZoneOver = e;
  }
}
```

This is the code sample for angular2-RC5 (current version as of this date). I higly suggest you upgrade to this version. Don't forget to add the directives to app.module.ts:

```
declarations: [
    ...
    FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES,
    ...
],
```

Comment: Actually i tried it but didnt worked can i post my code

Comment: First upgrade to RC5 and then try again.

Comment: stijn,i changed it but still no use